# In Scala 3, how does tuple type works?

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-3, hlist

I was told that Scala 3 tuple behave like shapeless HList in Scala 2, so I did a simple experiment:

```scala
    val tuple = (1, "String", 1.1)

    val _: *:[Int, *:[String, Double]] = tuple // not working

    val _: *:[Double, *:[String, Int]] = tuple // not working
```

either one of them should be working based on HList definition, how did this happen?

Full error:

```
[Error] /home/peng/git/dottyspike/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/dotty/NewTuple.scala:15:42: Found:    (tuple : (Int, String, Double))
Required: Int *: String *: Double

Explanation
===========

Tree: tuple
I tried to show that
  (tuple : (Int, String, Double))
conforms to
  Int *: String *: Double
but none of the attempts shown below succeeded:

  ==> (tuple : (Int, String, Double))  <:  Int *: String *: Double class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedTermRef class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType
    ==> (Int, String, Double)  <:  Int *: String *: Double class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType
      ==> (String, Double)  <:  String *: Double class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType
        ==> Double *: EmptyTuple.type  <:  Double class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedTypeRef  = false

The tests were made under the empty constraint

[Error] /home/peng/git/dottyspike/src/main/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/dotty/NewTuple.scala:17:42: Found:    (tuple : (Int, String, Double))
Required: Double *: String *: Int

Explanation
===========

Tree: tuple
I tried to show that
  (tuple : (Int, String, Double))
conforms to
  Double *: String *: Int
but none of the attempts shown below succeeded:

  ==> (tuple : (Int, String, Double))  <:  Double *: String *: Int class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedTermRef class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType
    ==> (Int, String, Double)  <:  Double *: String *: Int class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedAppliedType
      ==> Int  <:  Double class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedTypeRef class dotty.tools.dotc.core.Types$CachedTypeRef  = false

The tests were made under the empty constraint

two errors found
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct definition:

```scala
    val _: Int *: String *: Double *: EmptyTuple = tuple
```